# Inequalities with negative Sobolev

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In this paper I am read, it say that $||\triangle u||_{H^{-2}} \leq c||u||_{L^2}$, where $u$ solves the heat equation with zero boundary conditions on the boundary.  I am still getting use to negative Sobolev space.  Why this true please?  Also, does the same inequality true for $Au$ instead of laplace, say $A$ is second order divergence operator with suitable boundary condition.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For $u \in L^2$ one defines $\Delta u \in H^{-2} = (H_0^2)^*$ by
$$ \langle \Delta u, v \rangle := \int u \, \Delta v \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz, you find
$$ |\langle \Delta u , v \rangle | \le \| u\|_{L^2} \, \|\Delta v\|_{L^2}
\le C \, \|u\|_{L^2} \, \|v\|_{H_0^2}.$$
Hence, $\|\Delta u\|_{H^{-2}} \le C \, \|u\|_{L^2}$.

This should also answer your second question.

Comment: Ohhhh ok I just define $Au$ as same integration?  Then I need $A^{*}v$ on the inequality.  If we say $f$, then I am needing some Schauder thing for time right? Does such a thing exist?